# Probability that i is the largest number that occurred when throw dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

k dice are thrown. Compute the probabilities of the following two events:
 A - the largest number that occurred is i.

I tried the following solution but it is not equal to the final answer:

I Tried to define the size of A and then divide it by $$ {6^k} $$

|A| =  $$ { {k \choose 1} i^{k-1} } $$

(Need to choose place for "i" and than I have i options for each of the other places.

Any thoughts why it is wrong? thank you

Comment: You mention "two events"...

Comment: For the event $A$, Hint:  it is significantly easier to compute the probability that the largest element is $≤i$.  That's just $\frac {i^k}{6^k}$.

Comment: Note:  your computation is flawed as it multiply counts instances in which $i$ appears multiple times.

Comment: Thank you , I understand my mistake!

Comment: Hint: If rv $X$ denotes the largest number that occurs then $\{X=i\}$ and $\{X\leq i-1\}$ are disjoint events with $\{X=i\}\cup\{X\leq i-1\}=\{X\leq i\}$

Answer (score 0):

1. $P(n>i)=\left(\frac{6-n}{6}\right)^k$
2. $P(n<i)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{i-1}P(n=m)$
3. $P(n=i)=1-P(n>i)-P(n<i)$